# Give renderObj = IMAGE a class

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to use a lazy-loader for my images. Therefore I found a JS which seems pretty comfortable. Nevertheless, my images need a class="lazy" so that the JS knows which images it should affect.

The problem is, that I'm using a dynamically generated page with images which are stored in the media relation of each page. Idk if you guys understood what i meant :D

*But anyway, that's not the point.* The point is, I need a way to give the rendered images a class by TypoScript. **I'm looking for something like this:**

```
[...]

renderObj = IMAGE
renderObj {
    file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
    altText.data = file:current:title

    addClass = lazy
}

[...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **params** for this:

```
[...]

renderObj = IMAGE
renderObj {
    file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
    altText.data = file:current:title

    params = class="lazy"
}

[...]
```